# Insert string in MySQL in one column

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

(MySQL) I have a table with 2 columns.

Table 2 column is a varbinary column.

I have txt file that has 2040 binary strings converted to numbers ( ie 000001 = 000001 , 000100 = 000004 etc).

I am tring to find a statement to insert the data into table. i tried

```
 "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/ProjectFolder/MySQLHex/Hex.txt' INTO TABLE testbinary
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@col1,@col2) set representation=@col2; " .
```

It inserted all rows as NULL values.
If i manually insert 1 row (insert statment), it works !! How do i load the txt file into 2 column of the table using a command ?

Comment: So one single line would look something like `000001 = 000001`? If that is the case, you might need to add a `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `FIELDS TERMINATED BY '='` in your statement. Therefore the whole line is treated as one column.

It inserted all rows as NULL values, because you load the whole line from your txt file into variables, and just the second column (which is NULL because your whole line is in variable @col1) is set to the variable @col2.

Since you don't do any transformations or whatever with your variables, those are completely unnecessary in this case. Just insert directly into the columns, without using variables.